# jquery dropdownlist value set to 0

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

i have 1 controls as following

```
<div>
        Country<br />
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryId, new SelectList(Model.CountriesList, "CountryId", "CountryName"), "Please select one", new { style = "width: 250px;" })
    </div>
```

I am using jquery to empty this field

```
$('#CountryId').val('');
$('#CountryId').val('0');
$('#CountryId').text('');
$("#CountryId option[value='0']").val('');
$("input[name='CountryId']").val('');
```

I tried all the fabove things to empty the value of dropdownlist but none of them helped.

Also important point.
I am using Required Field Validator on country in my class.So that might be the issue.

Please tell me how to set the value of dropdown to 0;

Comment: `$('#CountryId').val('0')` should do the job, unless the value `0` is not found, do you have any options that is `value="0"` ?

Comment: Can you post your generated HTML (page source)?

Comment: yes as mentioned in the question i.e. "Please Select One" is at value="".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How does your select list look like.. Does it have a value= 0 in the first place ??
Try this

```
$("#CountryId option:eq(0)").attr('selected', true)
```

Check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/2Cg8C/)

Selected the option which is 5th item in the drop down

**UPDATED CODE**

For the select if the value is not mentioned and only text is present **then it considers the text as the value**..

So this should work in your case

```
$("#CountryId").val('Please select one')​
```

Check [UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/2Cg8C/2/)

Comment: How does your select list look like.. Looks like it has no value item with 0

Comment: yeah no value at 0.But make the val to ''.i.e. value=''

Comment: I have added some data in the post.. Check if that helps. Also it will be good if you can show the rendered html

Comment: Right click on the element and select inspect element in chrome.. Paste how the html looks in the browser here

Comment: <select style="width: 250px;" name="CountryId" id="CountryId" data-val-required="Required..." data-val="true"><option value="">Please select one</option>
<option value="US">United States of America</option>
<option value="CA">Canada</option>

Comment: value is empty here.. So try this $("#CountryId").val('')​

Comment: Try setting a value for the first option and then try.. Maybe  <option value="">Please select one</option>  AS   <option >0</option>

Comment: i cannot modify the value of options

Answer (score 1):

create a model class like below

```
public class Country
{
    [RegularExpression("([^0]*$)",ErrorMessage="please select country")]
    public int? Country_ID { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> CountryName{ get; set; }
}
```

now in your controller action write the below code...

```
    public ActionResult actionName()
    {
    Country model = new Country();
    var query = (from a in DbContext.Country
                         select new 
                         {
                             C_ID = a.ID,
                             Name = a.Name
                         }).ToList();
                model.CountryName = new SelectList(query, "C_ID", "Name").ToList();
                model.CountryName.Insert(0, new SelectListItem { Text = "--Select--", Value = "0" });

return View(model);
    }
```

now decorate your View like below

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Country_ID, Model.CountryName, new { id = "drpCountryId", Style = "width:150px;" })%>
<%:Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Country_ID, null, new { @class = "field-validation-message" })%>
```

i hope this might help you....

Answer (score 0):

Check This [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/nf3rm/)

```
$("select#CountryId")[0].selectedIndex = 1;
```

**HTML FIDDLE**

```
<select id="priority" name="priority">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="">-- Select Priority --</option>
<option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
</select>​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the following to clear selected values/set first value to be selected:

```
$('#CountryId option').first().prop('selected', true);
```

Or:

```
$('#CountryId').find('option').prop('selected',false);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below sets the first option "Please select one" to value `0`

```
$("#CountryId option:eq(0)").val(0).attr("selected", true);
```