# Select a DropDown by values with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<select id="id_deals-1-deal_template" name="deals-1-deal_template">
 <option selected="selected" value="">---------</option>
 <option value="1" selected="selected">Pear</option>
 <option value="2">Apple</option>
 <option value="4">Melon</option>
</select>
```

In order to select Melon I have to do this:

```
$('#id_deals-1-deal_template>option:eq(3)').prop('selected', true);
```

But I would rather have to select the primary key that is 4 in this case.
Hence is it possible to select a dropdown by its value rather than sequence?

Comment: like this [way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12560841/1074944)

Comment: $("#id_deals-1-deal_template option:eq(4)").val(4).attr("selected", true);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `.val` which can be a setter or getter based on the argument. Below is a setter..

```
$('#id_deals-1-deal_template').val(4);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#id_deals-1-deal_template').val(4);
```

Here is a demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/M3UBc/

Answer (score 1):

use

```
$('#id_deals-1-deal_template').val(4);
```

or

```
$('#id_deals-1-deal_template').val('Melon');
```

Answer (score 0):

Select by option name

```
$("#id_deals-1-deal_template option").each(function() {
    if($(this).text() == 'Melon') {
    $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');            
}                        
});
```

Select by value id

```
$("#id_deals-1-deal_template option").each(function() {
    if($(this).text() == '4') {
    $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');            
    }                        
});
```